# Codeigniter -> Extracting More Data

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I have the following code that confirms a activation with the database.  What I am wanting to no now is what is the best method to enable me so extract the users first name `userFirstName`   that is linked to the specific activation code? and how would I pass it as `$data['userFirstName'] = What` into the controller.

**Model:**

```
function confirmUser($activateCode)
{
    if($activateCode == '')
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
 //Selects the userID where the given URI activateCode = ?

    $this->db->select('userID');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('userActiveCode', $activateCode);

    $result = $this->db->get();

    if($result->num_rows == 1)  // If the above result is = 1 then update the userActive row else it will fail
    {
        $this->db->set('userActive', 1);
        $this->db->where('userActiveCode', $activateCode);
        $this->db->update('users');

        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a reference parameter to your model method to return the user's first name to the caller. This would allow a clean boolean return value.

**Model**

```
function confirmUser($activateCode, &$userFirstName) 
{ 
   if($activateCode == '') 
       return false;

    $this->db->select('userID, userFirstName'); 
    $this->db->from('users'); 
    $this->db->where('userActiveCode', $activateCode); 

    $result = $this->db->get(); 

    if($result->num_rows == 1)
    { 
        $this->db->set('userActive', 1); 
        $this->db->where('userActiveCode', $activateCode); 
        $this->db->update('users'); 

        $userFirstName = $result->row()->userFirstName;
        return true; 
    }
    else
        return false;     
}
```

**Caller**

```
$userFirstName = '';
if ($this->user_model->confirmUser($activate_code, $userFirstName))
    //userFirstName will be populated
    $data['userFirstName'] = $userFirstName;
else
    //userFirstName will still be empty
```

When passing-by-reference, as opposed to passing-by-value, you are essentially passing a pointer (memory address) to the spot in memory that holds the value rather than the actual value; therefore, when you change the value in the method, the parameter that was passed-by-reference by the caller also changes. This is because they are both pointing to the same exact memory address.

Answer (score 0):

If you update your select statement to grab `userFirstName` too, you will have access to it in your results:

```
// setting up the query
$this->db->select('userID, userFirstName');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('userActiveCode', $activateCode);

$result = $this->db->get();

if($result->num_rows == 1)
{
    $this->db->set('userActive', 1);
    $this->db->where('userActiveCode', $activateCode);
    $this->db->update('users');

    return $result->row()->userFirstName;
}else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

On the controller side, `confirmUser` now returns the username (if available) or `false` on failure. This allows you to do something like this:

```
if ($username = $my_model->confirmUser) {
  echo 'Welcome, ' . $username;
} else {
  echo 'Failed checking confirmation token';
}
```

Comment: Thanks again rjz,  Do I can this within the `TRUE`? & how would I pass it via the controller since the model requires a value?

Comment: Sure thing, sorry I couldn't be more help on the other! Yeah, I'd put it in the same conditional as your `TRUE`. In fact, you might consider using it as the return value. It will still test `true` on the other side as long as you're using the implicit equal (`==`, not `===`). Updating my answer...

Comment: Thanks,  is there anyway that I can access it like $this->users_model->confirmUser($activateCode)->userFirstName;

Comment: sure. Just use `return $result->row();` (omit the `userFirstName` bit) to return the entire query result.

Comment: Please note if you return the entire object, you will have issues referencing $this->users_model->confirmUser($activateCode)->userFirstName; in the event the UserModel::confirmUser method returns false. I recommend you stick with returning only the user's first name or false as rjz suggests in his answer. The other option is to use a reference parameter to return the first name to the caller. This approach would allow the model method to continue returning only a boolean. Let me know if you'd like me to post an answer demonstrating how to pass-by-reference.

Comment: @slypete Yes Please and thank you both I have never had so many clear examples and replies.